# MVC Way of Putting Multiple "Components" on a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this view called `CentralOffice` that will contain all the Central Office information. The `CentralOffice` view has multiple components. In React, Vue, and other javascript universes, everything is heavily 'componentized'. Basically, I need to display multiple views on one View that already has a layout page. Here is what I am looking for

> Central Office View.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Central Office";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Central Office</h2>
<div class="row">
   /// @*Display the BldgAddr view*@

</div>
<div class="row">
 ///   @*Display the getAdministrator view*@
</div>
```

> Address View

```
@model DirectoryMVC.Models.getbldgaddr_Result
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BldgAddr";
    Layout = "~/Views/CentralOffice/Data.cshtml";
}

   <h2>Building Address</h2> 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.address)
}
```

Administrator View is much the same, and below is the controller for Address for austerity.

```
public class BldgAddrController : Controller
    {
        private DirectoryEntities de;

        public BldgAddrController()
        {
            de = new DirectoryEntities();
        }
        // GET: BldgAddr
        public ActionResult BldgAddr(string district, string bldg_no)
        {
           getbldgaddr_Result bldgResult  = de.getbldgaddr(district, bldg_no, null).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(bldgResult);
        }
    }
```

What is the MVC way to accomplish this?

Comment: Partials. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial

Comment: Partials and/or Child Actions/View Components. Child Actions are applicable in MVC5 and less, whereas Core utilizes View Components for much the same functionality. You'd use partials when it's pretty much static HTML or the HTML varies only based on something readily available to the view (user authentication status, roles user is in, session variables, etc.). You'd utilize Child Actions/View Components when you need to do additional work before returning the view (querying a database, for example).